# Android head Unit not able to control volume programmatically

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-auto, android-automotive, android-tts

I installed NIPPON NDROID 9PRO 9.1Inch Android 10.1(MCU:T3L) Car Multimedia Player and Alpine external speakers in my vehicle. But not able to control volume programmatically.

I used this code to control volume

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, \_volume, if (showSystemUI) FLAG_SHOW_UI else 0)
```

But not able to control.
Any specific code to control hardware volume?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Google screwed up, no app can control volume on headunits including mine. I only read FCC launcher is able to do it.

Comment: @RonenFestinger I found how FCC launcher is controlling volume, They are using this libTWUtil.so library, I am not able to find this library anywhere
They are using android.tw.john.TWUtil package

Comment: @Sumit good catch, how did you find it out? Maybe we can contact them?